# Facebook Conversion API Gateway interaction with ad blockers

Tags: facebook-pixel, facebook-conversions-api

I'm trying to implement the Facebook Conversion API to improve ad attribution. One of the advertised features is the ability to bypass ad blocking (again, not to serve ads, but to track conversions).

Facebook also suggests using the Conversion API Gateway, which simplifies this implementation and handles event deduplication from the Facebook pixel. As I understand it, the pixel takes care of sending the events to our configured subdomain (e.g. `analytics.myco.com`) and the gateway forwards them to the Facebook Conversion API.

The problem is that if someone has an ad block, it will prevent the pixel from loading in the first place, so it won't send any events to the gateway. None of the Facebook documentation talks about any downsides to using the gateway versus direct integration (custom code on the backend triggered by the purchase completion event).

Am I missing something about serving the pixel from the gateway, or is the Facebook documentation just incomplete?

Answer (score 0):

I think it worth vetting if users have an adsblock if that will prevent tag from loading or not. adsblock is to block ads to a user but not to block tracking events to my understand

Answer (score 0):

I have the same concerns, in documentation and every tutorial I see that classic JS should send event to gateway. So browsers should not block this because gateway runs on your own subdomain.

But on my opinion it will be blocked by most of the adblockers. I have tested Ghostery extension and Vivaldi internal adblock and both have settings to block ads and/or **trackers**. And yes, both successfully prevented to load fbevents.js so event was not tracke